# Transparent text on transparent toolbar

Tags: html, css

I have a partially transparent nav bar and I would like to have the text on it be completely transparent.  The css I have here makes the text on the bar completely transparent, but it shows the slightly transparent toolbar beneath it.  I want the body background to show through the text.

Appreciate any help thanks!

```css
body {
  background: #db8669;
}

.header {
 z-index: 99;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 3rem;
 background-color: #00000077;
 color: #ffffff00;
 font-family: 'Encode Sans Expanded', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
}

.header:hover {
 color: #ffffffdd;
}

.header li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.header li:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}

.header li:hover {
 color: #ddffee;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.header ul {
  height: 3rem;
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
}

.header p {
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 font-size: 1rem;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-top: .3rem;
 margin-left: .3rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

.header .toolbar {
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

.header nav {
 margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
        <div class="toolbar">
          <div id="logo"><p>Joe Schmoe</p></div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li id=florallink>Florals</li>
              <li id=landscapelink>Landscapes</li>
              <li id=portraitlink>Portraits</li>
              <li id=stilllink>Still Life</li>
              <li id=mystorylink>My Story</li>
              <li id=eventslink>Events</li>
              <li id=contactlink>Contact Me</li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: so you basically want to punch holes in the header to show the background color of body ?

Comment: yeah, want to be able to see a bit of the background come through the bar, but the text to punch completely through to the background like you said.

Comment: If it's a flat background colour, go with Red's answer as it is the most widely supported. If you need the same effect over, say, a background image, you might want to look at `background-clip: text;`, but it's not supported in IE (or Edge IIRC) yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you try won't work. Because the text takes the color of its parent element if you make it transparent. It wont just go straight true the `header` element. Like @dirk said, 'punch holes' in it

You could just set the *text color* the same color as the body's *background color*. Which will give the idea that the text is 'punching holes into the header'.

```css
body {
  background: #db8669;
}

.header {
 z-index: 99;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 3rem;
 background-color: #000000aa;
 color: #ffffff00;
 font-family: 'Encode Sans Expanded', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
}

.header:hover {
 color: #db8669;
}

.header li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.header li:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}

.header li:hover {
 color: #dc8668;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.header ul {
  height: 3rem;
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
}

.header p {
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 font-size: 1rem;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-top: .3rem;
 margin-left: .3rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

.header .toolbar {
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

.header nav {
 margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
        <div class="toolbar">
          <div id="logo"><p>Joe Schmoe</p></div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li id=florallink>Florals</li>
              <li id=landscapelink>Landscapes</li>
              <li id=portraitlink>Portraits</li>
              <li id=stilllink>Still Life</li>
              <li id=mystorylink>My Story</li>
              <li id=eventslink>Events</li>
              <li id=contactlink>Contact Me</li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```